# Disable search suggestions based on current page

Tags: chrome-for-android

Chrome has recently started offering search suggestions based on whatever is currently in the tab when I enter the address bar, like this:

[image: Search Suggestions in Google Chrome]

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

From 3 dots menu → settings  → Sync and Google services →uncheck Autocomplete searches and URLs

Source: **[Chrome Privacy Whitepaper](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html)**